# Notice: Undefined index:work_homes_id in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ suu \ Classes \ PracaDomowa.php on line 150

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
public function add Solution ()
{
    $ userID = Session :: get ('id');

    $ idPracyDomowej = $ _POST ['homework_id'];

    $ content = $ _POST ['content'];

    $ transfer_name = date ('Y-m-d H: i: s');


    $ database = new Database ();
    $ BazaDanych-> connect ();

    $ query = 'INSERT INTO `solution` (
      `user_id`,` homework_id`, `content`,` upload_date`
    ) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ';

    $ query result = $ database-> query ($ query,
        [$ userID, $ homeID, $ content,
       $ DataPrzeslania]);

    if ($ inquiry result> 0) {
      Message :: success ('Solution successfully added!');
      header ('Location:'. Settings :: get ('appURL'). 'my-works');
    } else {
      Message :: error ('An error occurred while adding
      solutions!');
      header ('Location:'. Settings :: get ('appURL'). 'add-
      solution-form '); //
    }
}
```

Undefined index: work_homes_id in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ suu \ Classes \ PracaDomowa.php on line 150

Undefined index: tresc in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ suu \ Classes \ PracaDomowa.php on line 152

What is going on? Where is the mistake

Comment: What is the above code showing or doing? It doesn't look well formatted. Can we see PracaDomowa.php file or at least the code around line 152

Comment: The errors don't seem to come from that code snippet.

Comment: your columnnames have spaces at the beginning but that is not the issue here, you have no $_P'OST['work_homes_id '] here

Comment: It lets you add a solution to a given topic homework

Comment: Where can I put all the PracaDomowa.php code?